# Initialization of immutable value error on Swift?

Tags: swift, for-in-loop

I am trying to create an app where you can chose the type of chemistry you are interested in and it will give you information on that type. The only problem is that I am getting a error message stating the following:

`Initialization of immature value 'chemistry' was never used.`

On this block of code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    chemistryArray = [chemistryLabel0, chemistryLabel1, chemistryLabel2, chemistryLabel3, chemistryLabel4]

    for index in 0..<chemistryArray.count {

        let chemistry = chemistryArray[index]
    }
}
```

On this line:

```
let chemistry = chemistryArray[index]
```

I was wondering what this error message means and how to fix it.

Any suggestions or input is grealty appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: Tagging the question with [chemistry] was a joke, wasn't it?

Comment: That is a warning, not an error. And what is unclear about that? You assign a value to `chemistry` and never use that value.

Answer (score 0):

I think every other loop you declare `chemistry` again and never use it inside the loop. And as I was corrected this variable is not seen outside the scope of the for-loop.

So the purpose of the for-loop is ambiguous.

Sorry, I would rather comment but I cannot yet.

Comment: `chemistry` is not "reinitialized", and `var` won't make the warning go away. It is a new variable for each loop iteration, and the scope is limited to the loop body, so  *"you end up with chemistry that holds the last member"* is at least misleading.

Comment: Yes, you right. I think I got confused too. Let me fix it

Answer (score 0):

As *Martin R* already explained, you are declaring and populating the constant `chemistry` but **you are not using it**.

Since `chemistry` is declared within the `{ }` of the `for loop`, it does exist only inside that scope.

So the compiler, looking at your code, cannot figure out (me neither :) the meaning of your code and it is producing a warning to grab your attention.

In other words the compiler is telling you something like:

> Dear coder,
>
> I will compile this code but are you sure it is correct? Because this instruction does not make sense to me.
>
> Regards
>
> *The compiler*

### The fixing

To fix the warning you just need to use the constant or remove it.

### Now my question

Why are you declaring and populating a constant and you are not using it?